# Как сделать фон сайта из разных gif

Tags: html, css, gif

Пытаюсь сделать фон из нескольких gif-картинок. Хотелось бы чтобы и справа была гифка и слева, и соответственно так же вверху и внизу. Делаю так на странице, пока получилось по центру одну влепить. Может знаете как это правильно реализовать.

```
<head>      
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>С Днюхой !!!</title>   
        <link href="tipaStili.css" rel="stylesheet">    
        <style>
            html {
            height: 100%; 
            background: #000 url(2.gif) 
            no-repeat center;   
            }
        </style>
</head>
```

получаеться вот такое [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам нужно использовать свойства: position, left, right, top, bottom. Справка - тут http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: @nick_n_a я не могу в свой код еще добавить gif-ок, только одна отображается, может у вас есть пример какой нибудь?

Comment: Фон может быть один. Не знаю можно ли "скомбинировать". Расставьте img или div задайте им например `position:float right:0px;width:ширина картинки` и т д. Поддерживают ли браузеры прозрачность - png - да. gif - нет.

Comment: Ну да, так фейерверки залазят за gif-ки, спасибо за помощь, оставлю одну по центру.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью `background-position` можно поменять расположение. Загуглите, чтобы узнать подробней. Можете также добавить это в в ваш background. Чтобы сделать 4 штуки, можете попробовать так:

```
<head>      
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>С Днюхой !!!</title>   
        <link href="tipaStili.css" rel="stylesheet">    
        <style>
            html {
            height: 100%; 
            background: 
            #000 url(1.gif) no-repeat top left,
            #000 url(2.gif) no-repeat top right,
            #000 url(3.gif) no-repeat bottom left,
            #000 url(4.gif) no-repeat bottom right;
            }
        </style>
</head>
```

Плюсом можете редактировать ширину и высоту индивидуально. Вместо top, left и т.д. можете использовать проценты, пиксели, и т.д.

Comment: хм, так гифок вообще нет.

Comment: Адрес гифок поменяли, я надеюсь, на нужные?

Comment: Да. Ну они у меня там же где и первая, так что адрес такой же, просто переименовал гифки с 1-4

Comment: width: 100% должно помочь. А вот высоту было необязательно указывать.

Comment: + может лучше это всё применить для body вместо html? Для html сделайте width: 100%, в остальном всё, эти стили указываете для body вместо html.